# Woocommerce create order in android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with creating an order with woocommerce Api.
I know how to create coupon (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#create-a-coupon)
I use parameters like this

```
 mRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, RESOURCE_URL);


        //TODO maybe couldnt generate coupon right
        //Add parameters to specifi coupon
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("code", coding);
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("discount_type", "percent");
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("amount", String.valueOf(value));
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("individual_use", String.valueOf(true));
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("usage_limit", "1");
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("exclude_sale_items", String.valueOf(true));
        mRequest.addQuerystringParameter("expiry_date", String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-" + String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1));

        service.signRequest(new Token("", ""), mRequest);
```

And that generate coupon nice. But when I want to create order I don't know what to write into parameters because in http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#create-an-order documentation there is no tutorial for java coding. In create order I have to use many more parameters. I know how to add parameter with "payment_method" for example but in billing there are another parameters. I dont know how to define parameters right. Can you help me please?